# Format temporal duration between in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I stored the **localdatetime()** in post node as timestamp, I don't want to display the post, if post age crossed 24 hours. So I wrote below query

```
MATCH (n:Post) return duration.between(localdatetime() ,n.timestamp+duration({hours:24})) as expiry
```

I'm getting response something like this.

> P0M1DT-15207.548000000S
>
> P0M1DT-4721.134000000S

But I want to display remaining time in client side (javascript) as hh:mm:ss format. So How to format this temporal format into specific format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duration and datetime functionality is still being worked on as of 3.4.4, and easy formatting options are missing. You can piece together what you need by [accessing the components of the durations](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-accessing-components-durations):

```
MATCH (n:Post) 
WITH duration.inSeconds(localdatetime() ,n.timestamp+duration({hours:24})) as expiry
RETURN expiry.hours,  + ':' + expiry.minutesOfHour + ':' + expiry.secondsOfMinute as expiry
```

If you need more consistent formatting options, including the ability to pad out each separate field to 2 digits, you'll need APOC Procedures for this, notably [apoc.text.format()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_text_functions):

```
MATCH (n:Post) 
WITH duration.inSeconds(localdatetime() ,n.timestamp+duration({hours:24})) as expiry
RETURN apoc.text.format('%02d:%02d:%02d', [expiry.hours, expiry.minutesOfHour, expiry.secondsOfMinute]) as expiry
```

As for defaulting to 00:00:00 when the expiry has expired, you can use a CASE statement on the value of the deadline before you get the duration between then and now:

```
WITH localDateTime() as now
MATCH (n:Post) 
WITH now, n.timestamp + duration({hours:24}) as deadline
WITH now, CASE WHEN now > deadline THEN now ELSE deadline END as deadline
WITH duration.inSeconds(now, deadline) as expiry
RETURN apoc.text.format('%02d:%02d:%02d', [expiry.hours, expiry.minutesOfHour, expiry.secondsOfMinute]) as expiry
```

Comment: Thats really cool, but expird time showing negative minutes and seconds like this **-4:-57:-25**

Comment: Do you want to display 00:00:00 when the duration has expired completely?

Comment: Made the change that should return 00:00:00 when the deadline has passed.

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of whole days (as an integer) between 2 datetimes (`a` and `b`), use this:

```
duration.inDays(a, b).days
```

For example (assuming `n.timestamp` is a neo4j DateTime object):

```
MATCH (n:Post)
RETURN duration.inDays(localdatetime(), n.timestamp).days as nWholeDays;
```

and:

```
MATCH (n:Post)
RETURN duration.inDays(localdatetime(), n.timestamp).days > 0 AS atLeast24HoursOld;
```